# How to simulate asp:imagebuttom on asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, imagebutton

i'm creating a form on asp.net mvc 2 and i need to submit my form data. Is there a simple way to submit a form with a input[type="image"] (like asp:imagebuttom) but without use javascript to call the form submit event?

thanks in advance for some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no particular magic for submit buttons in MVC. Just create a standard image input inside the form.

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
     <!-- Your form -->

     <input type="image" src="xxx.png" alt="Save data" />
<% } %>
```

Image inputs are submit buttons in HTML, so you don't need to add any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would style an input[type=submit] button, to look like an image.